# How to get last level category of each product in magento

Tags: product, category-products

I am trying to get last level category name with its product count for each product on listing page. explained as below-

```
Category
                -> Sub-category 1
                          ->Sub-sub-category 11   -> Product 1
                          ->Sub-sub-category 12 
                              -> Sub-sub-sub-category 13  ->Product 2  
                -> Sub-category 2
                          ->Sub-sub-category 21 
                              -> Sub-sub-sub-category 22  ->Product 3 
                          ->Sub-sub-category 23   -> Product 4
```

I want to get  only categories "**Sub-sub-category 11**", "**Sub-sub-sub-category 13**", "**Sub-sub-sub-category 22**" and "**Sub-sub-category 23**" which are the last level categories of Products 1, Products 2, Products 3, Products 4.
I found below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926118/get-last-level-category-name-of-a-product-in-magento but it only gets third level category.

Comment: are you need on product listing page (category lading page)?

Comment: @Abdul. yes I need it on listing page.

Answer (score 1):

Try bellow code on product listing block or list.phtml

```
public function currentCategory()    
{
    // Put here your current category id 
    $currentCategoryId = 3;
    $category =  Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategoryId);

    //OR $category = Mage::registry('current_category');

    $this->lastLevelCategory($category,2);
}
public function lastLevelCategory($category, $level=0)
{
    $html = '';
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('all_children')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);

    $collection->setLoadProductCount(true);
    $children = $collection->addIdFilter($category->getChildren());

    if ($children) {
        foreach ($children as $i => $child) {
            $this->lastLevelCategory($child, $level+1);
        }
        if(!$category->getChildren()) {
            $html .= "Category Name : ".$category->getName().'<br>';
            $html .= "Product Count : ".$category->getProductCount().'<br>';
        }
    }
    echo $html;
}
```